# How I solve this -> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, error-handling, windows-10, virtual-machine, netbeans-8

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
>   Unrecognized option: -
>   C:\Users\Win 8.1 Pro\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

I tried to setting in control panel and not work.
I downloaded JRE 1.8.0_191 but I don't really understand to use it...
How can I solve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions:1.Check the Java environment

2.Some programs have memory setting and some memory setting is set beyond VM range.

3.Check if `java.exe`、`javaw.exe`、`javaws.exe` are generated under `C:\Windows\System32`,just delete them.

4.Displays the definition parameters in the environment variables to set the VM size.
Global environment variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS

value:-Xmx512m

Comment: thank you for your suggestion :( but now I have new problem.. 'Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1024M'

Comment: Did you have any application override the Java configuration, if you have ,delete them maybe is ok.Or you can delete all Java settings except JAVA_HOME and CLASSPATH.

Comment: @Winda Agusthia Netto If my answer is useful please vote or mark my answer.Thank you.